# Queue of Nodes (Linked-list) C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, nodes

I'm trying to store Nodes in a queue (STL), but I'm getting an error.

First of all, I want to know if the struct of the Node is right.

Really, I want to store the Nodes in order of integers (small to big), I heard of the priority queue, I tried to use it, but I was getting a big error so I went back to a queue.

Then I saw something about operator overloading of the Nodes but I don't re4ally geting how to use that. Will have have to make a Node.h file?

```
struct Node{
  int freq;
  char Char;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right;
  Node(int freq, char Char){
  freq = freq;
  Char = Char;
 }
};

queue<Node*> list;
Node *a = new Node(2, '4');

list.push(a);

Node *e = list.pop();
cout << e->freq;
```

ERROR:

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be // Node *e = list.pop();
```

Comment: isn't your Node constructor going to assign values from parameters back in to parameters instead of initialize members in the struct?

Comment: You don't need the `left` and `right` members.

Comment: @bitmask I'm going to need them cause I'm building a Binary Tree with the same Nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pop` is `void` function. You need `front` :

```
list.pop();
Node *e = list.front();
```

Next problem is the constructor:

```
Node(int freq, char Char){
  this->freq = freq; // <------- 'this->' is added to access to right variables
  this->Char = Char; // <-------
 }
```

My suggestion is write your constructor like below:

```
Node(int freq, char Char) : freq(freq), Char(Char)
{
}
```

Comment: Output should be 2 but I'm getting a large random number.

Comment: @AdegokeA: You have a problem in your constructor. See my answer again